# What does this loop do?

Tags: algorithm, math, puzzle

What does the following loop do?

```
k = 0
while(b!=0): 
   a = a^b 
   b = (a & b) << 1 
   k = k + 1
```

where `a`, `b` and `k` integers.

Initially `a` = 2<sup>779</sup> and `b` = 2<sup>62</sup>  then what will be the value of `k` after the termination of the loop?

I'd be happy if you people try solving the problem manually rather than programmatically.

**EDIT** : Dropping the tags c and c++. How can I solve the problem manually?

Comment: `a` cannot equal 2<sup>779</sup> in standard C or C++ unless you've defined a custom numeric type. If you do have one, why not just **try it**?

Comment: My only intention is to know how the loop works?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Well, if `a`, `b`, and `k` were some C++ class which overloaded `^`, `&`, `<<`, `=`, `!=`, and `+`, then this code would be valid.

Comment: @NOVELMOK What do you mean by "how it works"? Do you know what each operator does?

Comment: @NOVELMOK: Do you want us to walk you through the math and explain the meaning of the operators? I'm really not sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 4):

After this chunk is executed:

```
a = a^b ;
b = (a & b) << 1;
```

`b` will take on the integer representation of whatever bits were both set in `b` and not set in `a`. Assuming that the input numbers will be of the form 2<sup>x</sup>, `a` will become `a` + `b`, and `b` will be itself multiplied by 2 (due to shifting). This means that the loop will terminate when the MSB of `a` and `b` are the same (which will be 780th bit in this example). Since `b` starts off at the 63th bit, there will eventually be 718 iterations: 780 - 63 + 1 (the last iteration) = 718.

You can see this when you step through this with `a` = 2<sup>1</sup> and `b` = 2<sup>0</sup>:

```
a = 10
b = 01
k = 0

a = 11
b = 10
k = 1

a = 01 (a + b no longer holds here, but it is irrelevant as this is the termination case)
b = 00
k = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

> What does the following loop do?

**It computes [power of a] - [power of b] + 1**

If you look at the bit-patterns it becomes quite clear. For initial values of a = 2<sup>10</sup> and b = 2<sup>5</sup> it looks like this:

```
k =  0, a = 10000000000, b =       100000
k =  1, a = 10000100000, b =      1000000
k =  2, a = 10001100000, b =     10000000
k =  3, a = 10011100000, b =    100000000
k =  4, a = 10111100000, b =   1000000000
k =  5, a = 11111100000, b =  10000000000
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/9gyJC) is an ideone.com demo.

For the values you mention in your post I get k = 718.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't mention what does the loop do. Your answer is of no use to me.

Comment: @NOVEL: Well, isn't that a coincidence. Your question is of no use to us.

Comment: @Billy ONeal : Then just ignore the question. You might have got better things to do.

Comment: Hmm... interesting timing of the update. I will assume it is merely a coincidence, but I point out to NOVELMOK that the reasoning behind this can be found in my answer.

Comment: Ah. I only read half your answer... Thought it was another answer explaining what the bitwise operations did. Good find Paul.

Answer (score 0):

In a language that supports numbers this big, the answer is 718, and the question is not at all interesting either way.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't mention how does the loop works? Your answer is of no use to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the loop is performing a series of bitwise operations while incrementing `k` by 1 at each iteration.

There's a decent-looking tutorial about bitwise operators [here.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have no problem with the loop whatsoever. I just want to know how to figure out the result of the problem manually.

Comment: Okay. In that case, you should probably read the tutorial I posted a link to - that explains what each operator does. Once you understand that, you should be able to calculate the results manually.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that a qnd b is an integer, i think the value 2<sup>779</sup> is too big for a integer variable to accommodate this is same for the variable b 2<sup>62</sup> as well. So both will have there minimum value I think , so after executing  a = a^b ;
b = (a & b) << 1; these statements the value of a and be will be 0. and k's value will be equal to 1. Since b is 0 , the while loop's condition will be false and it will exit the loop.

**EDIT :** The answer is applicable for a programming language like C/C++ or C#

Answer (score 0):

It's not really C syntax.. If we consider that the code is sequential, I am agree with @Paul. But, considering that

```
a + b == (a^b) + ((a&b) << 1)
```

where `a^b` is the sum without applying carry from each bit, and `(a&b)<<1` is carry from each bit, we could say that it performs a sum, **IFF** C code would be

```
int k = 0;
while(b){ 
   int old_a = a;
   a = a^b;
   b = (old_a & b) << 1; // note that the need the original value of a here
   k++;  // number of recursion levels for carry
};
```

The difference in code could be because of "paralel" way of execution in  the original code (or language).